# Formula to put a date together seperatly Fields "Month" and "Year"?

Tags: formula, date

In an custom Oject, that is filled with external market development data I got a picklist field "Month" (Picklist: 1,2,3,4...12) and a picklist field "Year" (picklist: 1990, 1991, 1992... 2020). Each record represents a value for a certain calendar Month. How is it possible to get Salesforce to know that "Year = 2001" and  "Month = 5" in one record the period "May 1st 2001 till May 31st 2001" represents. I Need to have Reports and Dashboards showing the market development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below steps to create a new Date type formula field

1. Go to Setup -> Create -> Object
2. Click on Create new Field
3. Select Formula from list.
4. Type Formula Name and Select Date and return type
5. Type Following in your formula

   ```
   DATEVALUE(text( Year__c) & '-' & text(Month__c) & '-' & '01')
   ```

[Reference guide to Date formula](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&siteLang=en_US#DATE)

Comment: Error: Field Year__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions. Tell me more

Comment: put all picklist value inside TEXT(Year__c) formula.

Comment: What field typ would work? Text, Number, ...?

Comment: make return type as Date

Comment: Now I get: Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Text

Comment: DATEVALUE(  TEXT(Year__c) - TEXT ( Month__c ) - "01")

Comment: you are doing concatenation of string so update them as shown in answer ;)

Comment: DATEVALUE( TEXT( Year__c ) - TEXT( Month__c ) - "1" )

Comment: Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Text

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: DATEVALUE(" TEXT( Year__c ) - TEXT( Month__c ) - 1 ")

Comment: please check updated answer. it will be DATEVALUE(text( Year__c) & '-' & text(Month__c) & '-' & '01')

Comment: Thank You, for your help, finally only the "" were missing to get an Syntax Check OK.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the formula that is working well is:

"DATEVALUE( Year__c & "-" & Month__c & "-" & "01" )"

The field typ of MONTH and YEAR are both (text). The transfering from a picklist value did not work, evan that the Syntax check was positiv.